# How to bind the result of a recordset of a subform after executing the query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have hard coded multiple sqlQueries:

```
sQueryCurrencyRate = "SELECT * FROM Table.Mytable WHERE  As_Of_Date =" & Format(dateField.value, "M/d/yyyy")


 sQueryCurrencyUsDollar = "SELECT * FROM Table.Mytable WHERE  As_Of_Date =" & Format(dateField.value, "M/d/yyyy")
```

Now I have made a function that will execute the query (I think it's not the optimal way) but this is what I'm trying :

```
Function executeQuery(strSQL As String)

Dim dbs As DAO.Database

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Dim rst As Recordset, db As DAO.Database, fld As Field
'Open a snapshot-type Recordset based on an SQL statement
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
Do Until rst.EOF
   For Each fld In rst.Fields: MsgBox fld
  rst.MoveNext
Loop
End Function
```

**What I need :**

Fill the subform by the result of the executeQuery function

```
 Me.subForm_displayQueries.SourceObject = executeQuery(sQueryCurrencyRate).result
```

How to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Set the sub forms recordsource to be strSQL.  Your function `Function executeQuery(strSQL As String)` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav That is what I'm trying to achieve ,making the function `executeQuery` in a way where It could return a result and after that set the result in the subform

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Oh I think I know what you mean , I will try it thank you

Comment: Read about functions then.  `Function executeQuery(strSQL As String) as Recordset` then you can do `set executeQuery=rst`  but you can just modify the subforms source query.

Comment: See [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/bind-a-form-to-an-ado-recordset?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for how to bind a form to an ADO recordset. You're using a DAO one, but you could just as easily use an ADO one

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve here.. this method will perform poorly for larger data sets. Like @Nathan_Sav says, why don't you just set the sql to the form's recordsource directly? ie: me.RecordSource = strSQL